# Sum using where clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to Sum the value in a certain column, based upon if the text in a separate column matches certain criteria. I am trying to use the Where clause to do this, and keep getting 0 as an answer.

Table

| Person | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 70 |
| B | 85 |
| C | 50 |
| D | 100 |
| E | 20 |

I want to get a Sum of the Score Column for Persons A, D, E. I expect to get this

| Sum(Score) |
| --- |
| 190 |

Here is the expression I am using, where the Sum is incorrectly returned as 0

```
SELECT SUM (Score) 
FROM T*
WHERE Person = 'A' OR 'D' OR 'E';
```

Comment: You should have got an error here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `where`, when using `OR` you must type the column name again, so you could do:

```sql
WHERE Person = 'A' OR Person = 'D' OR Person = 'E';
```

or do better, using `IN`:

```
WHERE Person IN ('A', 'D', 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your looking for the [`IN ()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator:

```
SELECT SUM (Score) 
FROM T*
WHERE Person IN ('A', 'D', 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT person, SUM (Score) 
FROM T
WHERE Person = 'A' OR 'D' OR 'E'
Group by 
person
```

You could also change this 'or's to presented above 'in' structure